# Using recursion create a program that returns odd numbers from an array as a string in a specific format c#

Tags: c#, arrays, recursion

The string should look like this "[1,3,5,7]" I tried different versions of this code but I always either have too many commas or not enough. For example for this array "[2,4,7,8,10]" i get "[7,]".

```
static string ZwrocNieparzyste1(int[] tab, int i = 0)
{
    if (tab.Length == 1)
        if (tab[i] % 2 == 1)
            return string.Format("[{0}]", tab[i]);
        else
            return "[]";
    if (tab.Length == 0)
        return "[]";
    if (i == 0)
        if (tab[i] % 2 == 1)
            return string.Format("[{0},{1}", tab[i], ZwrocNieparzyste1(tab, i + 1));
        else
            return string.Format("[{0}", ZwrocNieparzyste1(tab, i + 1));
    if (i < tab.Length - 1)
        if (tab[i] % 2 == 1)
            return string.Format("{0},{1}", tab[i], ZwrocNieparzyste1(tab, i + 1));
        else
            return string.Format("{0}", ZwrocNieparzyste1(tab, i + 1));
    else
        if (tab[i] % 2 == 1)
        return string.Format("{0}]", tab[i]);
    else
        return "]";
}
```

Comment: Why specifically do you want recursion? Since this is a one liner in LINQ...

Comment: Have a think about what happens if one invocation gets this scenario `return string.Format("{0},{1}", tab[i], ZwrocNieparzyste1(tab, i + 1));` and the next gets `return "]";`

Comment: It isn't unclear what exactly you want to do, and how you would like to use recursion

Comment: @mjwills I am preparing for an exam and they ask us to use specific methods to solve tasks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is too much convoluted... To much difficult to comprehend. An example about how it could be simplified:

```
public static string PrintRecursive(int[] nums)
{
    if (nums.Length == 0)
    {
        return "[]";
    }

    return PrintRecursiveImpl(nums, 0, false);
}

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="nums">The array of numbers</param>
/// <param name="ix">The ix that perhaps will be printed</param>
/// <param name="alreadyPrintedNumber">Do we need to prepend a comma?</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static string PrintRecursiveImpl(int[] nums, int ix, bool alreadyPrintedNumber)
{
    string ret = string.Empty;

    if (ix == 0)
    {
        ret = "[";
    }

    if (nums[ix] % 2 == 1)
    {
        if (alreadyPrintedNumber)
        {
            ret += ", ";
        }

        ret += nums[ix];
        alreadyPrintedNumber = true;
    }

    if (ix + 1 < nums.Length)
    {
        ret += PrintRecursiveImpl(nums, ix + 1, alreadyPrintedNumber);
    }
    else
    {
        ret += "]";
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Note that I've splitted the "special case" `nums.Length == 0` from the other cases. So there are two methods, a "public" method to make the printing start and a private recursive method that "prints" the numbers.